# ggrain package, raincloud plots -- Positioning Density Aspect

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with ggrain package to achieve publishable raincloud plots. These plots are looking at a change in Y from Time 1 to Time 2. Therefore, only one group is being plotted. My original data frame is called BSL1

The issue:

I am trying to achieve the look where the density (violin) aspect of the plots overlap each other. I wish to keep the bar plots at their respective distances, but then move the pre density plot to overlap the post density plot. See attached image for example. This example is not perfect because it does not contain the bar plots, but still the moving of the density plot is most important.

Desired Output Look :

[image]
[[image]
I figured I could use arguments such as violin.args.position =  ….. but I had no success with this. Is anyone able to help? Thanks

````
## Get to know the data

Head(BSL1)

bslzpost bslpre studyid

1        7     25     111

2       20     14     112

3       24     52     114

4       65     68     121

5       74     79     122

6       NA     71     123

 

## Libraries

```{r}

library(ggrain)

library(tidyverse)

library(tidyr)

library(dplyr)

library(ggpp)

```

 

# Convert Data to Long Format

```{r}

BSL_long = gather(BSL, key = "Time", value = "Measurement", bslzpost, bslpre)

```

 

## Raincloud plot

```{r, warning=FALSE}

ggplot(BSL_long[BSL_long$Time %in% c('bslpre', 'bslzpost'),], aes(Time, Measurement, fill = Time)) +

  geom_rain(alpha = .5, rain.side = 'f1x1', id.long.var = "studyid",

            violin.args = list(color = NA, alpha = .6)) +

ggsignif::geom_signif(

  comparisons = list(c("bslpre", "bslzpost")),

  map_signif_level = TRUE) +

  theme_classic() +

  scale_fill_manual(values=c("dodgerblue", "darkorange")) +

  scale_color_manual(values=c("dodgerblue", "darkorange")) +

  guides(fill = 'none', color = 'none')

```
````

Output :

[image]

Comment: Could you share enough of your data to make the plot reproducible? Maybe the ouput of `dput(BSL_long)` if possible? Note that in the example you give, the data structure is different from yours. There are two groups that are coloured differently, and these are shown pre and post. You are showing a single group pre and post.

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes, in the desired output I show, there are two groups whereas my data only has one. Still, my desired output entails to move the leftmost density plot to overlay the right density plot, irregardless of number of groups.
 
I will provide the output for dput(BSL_long) tomorrow when I am with the data! Thank you.